# Incremental linear backoff in Spring Retry

Tags: java, spring-el, spring-retry

I am using the following annotation in a method that I would like retried:

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
private boolean myMethod() {
    ...
}
```

This retry is working as expected, as well as an exponential delay that's not shown. I would like to use a linear incremental retry as opposed to an exponential one (so first a 1-second wait, then 2-second, 3-second, etc.) in some cases. It sounds like I need `delayExpresion`, but I'm not familiar with SpEL to know what to use here. I tried:

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, delayExpression = "#{delay + 1000}"))
```

Is what I'm trying to do (where delay is incremented by 1000) possible with SpEL? Or perhaps, is my approach to the linear retry even correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't possible via annotations.

The `Retryable` has an `interceptor()` option:

```
/**
 * Retry interceptor bean name to be applied for retryable method. Is mutually
 * exclusive with other attributes.
 * @return the retry interceptor bean name
 */
String interceptor() default "";
```

So, you should consider to build a `RetryOperationsInterceptor` bean via `RetryInterceptorBuilder` and inject there a custom `BackOffPolicy` with desired linear logic.

Comment: The current delay is not available as a variable to the SpEL expressions and, in any case, the expression is not evaluated on each delivery attempt, just once during initialization. So, as Artem said, the only solution is a custom `BackOffPolicy` via an `interceptor`.

Comment: I see. Took your advice and created a `RetryOperationsInterceptor` bean with a custom `BackOffPolicy`, then went through `interceptor` in `Retryable`. This is working nicely. Thank you!